# How to show Messagebox from MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, messagebox

can anyone please tell about showing message box from MVC controller?
The scenario is - 
I want to show a message box with Yes/No buttons. On clicking Yes i want to show a confirmation message box.
I want to do this using MVC controller?
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,
Kaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (confirm('Are you sure?'))
{
$.post("Confirmation", {myresponse: 'yes'}, function(data)
{
$.("#mymodal").html(data);
}
}
```

That way it hits the actionmethod and lets it know that a yes confirmation was made and the actionmethod can send back the html markup.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the client message box? If so, try to use JavaScript's confirm dialog.

> ```
> if (confirm('Are you sure?')){}
> ```

Comment: I want to show the client message box but i want to show it from  controller's action method.

Comment: In order the client will see a dialog, you need to send him this code. The <i>right</i> place to do such, is the view. but of course you can pass this code to the view from the action method.

Answer (score 0):

The Controller's action method generally does not control what the View renders, rather it simply states which view to display (ie. return `this.View("MyView")`) and the data the view should use to rendering itself if necessary.

You can use `JavaScriptResult` however you are breaking separation of concerns somewhat, the Controller should dictate which view to render, not what the view contains.

Here's a good write up on JavaScriptResult and why it's a bad idea: http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/02/07/beware-of-asp-net-mvc-javascriptresult.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

On the controller side you want the method to return json.